# Catan Junior: When drawing the "pirate ghost" Coco (parrot) card to move the ghost, do you recieve resources?

Tags: catan-junior

The rules for Catan Junior, for the "Coco" card with the Ghost Captain state:

> Move the Ghost Captain as if you had rolled a ‘6’

The description of rolling a 6 says you move the ghost captain *and* take 2 resources.  Do you take resources when moving the captain in that case?

Its not clear from the wording for the Coco card whether you should take two resources as you normally would with the ghost.

If you *do* take resources there is almost no downside to building Coco cards.

(Sorry about the incorrect tag - I just joined, so I couldn't create a `catan-junior` tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just got this game for our daughter for Christmas and have only played it once. Just as with regular settlers, there is no downside to building development cards so I would say there is no downside to building Coco cards as well. The description says

> You move the ghost captain and take 2 resources.

Then move the ghost captain and take the two resources. I believe the inclusion of

> as if you had rolled a ‘6’

is where the implication of taking the two resource cards comes in. It would be the same as playing a knight in Settlers. You still move the robber and take a resource from another player.

Comment: I concur. I've played many times with my kids and we always take the two resource tiles when placing the ghost captain from a coco card.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Dutch manual here, and it literally states that you get to take two resources from the stockpile when moving the Ghost Pirate ("Kapitein Haak" in my book) using a Coco-card.

> De speler verplaatst Kapitein Haak direct naar een ander landschapsveld naar keuze en neemt twee fiches 'een en ander' van de betreffende soort.

---

> The player immediately moves the Ghost Captain to another tile of their choice and receives two resource cards of that type.

'Een en ander' would translate to 'Resource'- an attempt from the translators to avoid the word 'grondstof', i guess. So it specifically states that when you throw a 6 (it's also explicitly in the rules for rolling a 6) or move the captain to a tile by means of a Coco-card, you receive 2x the resource that this new tile could produce.